# Problem on Lipschitz condtion [uniqueness of a solution]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the functions defined as follows satisfies lips. condition in Rectangle $R$ defined by
$$R=\{(x,y): |x| \le a , |y| \le b,f(x,y)=x^2⋅e^{x+y}\},$$ where  $f(x,y)$ is the first order derivative.
What i want to prove here is the uniqueness of the solution of the D.E.
I must prove that $| f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2) | \le k·|y_1-y_2|$
Now, $|f(x,y_1) - f(x, y_2)| = | x^2·e^{x+y_1} - x^2·e^{x+y_2} |
=|x^2·e^xe^{y_1}-e^{y_2}| = x^2·e^x· |e^{y_1}-e^{y_2}|$ (since $x^2·e^x$ is positive)
But I didn't know what to do now.
Is $| e^{y_1} - e^{y_2} | \le | y_1 -y_2 |$ ???

Comment: I tried my best with commands but it doesn't seem to work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can use the mean value theorem $$f(b)-f(a)=f'(\xi)(b-a)$$ so you will have $$|e^{y_1}-e^{y_2}|\le e^{\xi}|y_1-y_2|$$ and $$\xi\in (y_1,y_2)$$